# How can HTTP client Detect if the transport connection to the HTTP server disconnect

Tags: go

I have been programming in golang for some few months to develop an HTTP server.
There are two things i would like to know if it is possible to achieve.

1. I have an HTTP client that does a persistence connection to the HTTP server as show below

```
func SendRequest(inputData []byte, VarPath string) (model.RecData, *http.Response, error) {
    var (
        localVarHTTPMethod = http.MethodPut
        returnValue        model.RecData
        c                  = NewConfiguration()
    )
    req, err := http.NewRequest(localVarHTTPMethod, VarPath, bytes.NewBuffer(inputData))
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    req.Close = true
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    backoff := 1
    for {
        res, err := NetH2Client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("Trying to send data ...")
            backoff *= 2
            if backoff > 20 {
                backoff = 20
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(backoff) * time.Second)
            continue
        }

        defer res.Body.Close()

        bodybytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
        res.Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            return returnValue, res, err
        }
        json.Unmarshal(bodybytes, &returnValue)
        fmt.Println("Successfully REGISTERED to NRF...")
        return returnValue, res, nil

    }

}
```

My question is, is it possible to detect at the client if the transport connection between client the server disconnect after initial successful connection. For example, the client at first send a PUT request to the server and got a response. Later at some point the server shutdown. Is it possible to detect this shutdown at the client so that the client start a new retry request until the the server is up and running. If possible any help on how to achieve this at the client above.

2. My second question is also about multiple HTTP client polling an HTTP server randomly with a PATCH request to update a resource at the server running in front of MongoDB.
   My question, is it possible detect at the server if a specific client stop polling. I would like to detect at the HTTP server if a specific client stop polling and then remove its resources after some time from the database. The clients does the polling with same URL but with different IDs in the URL. For example [https://x.x.x.x/dddddd/{ids}](https://x.x.x.x/dddddd/%7Bids%7D). Is this possible and also need help as to how to implement it. Am using gorilla/mux package for the server.

About the polling, this is what i have tried but am not able to get the time difference in order to make the decision to delete the resource.

```
type Server struct {
    idtime map[string]time.Time
}

var my = Server{}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    usersData := r.PathPrefix("/users").Subrouter()
    usersData.Path("/{id}").Methods(http.MethodPatch).HandlerFunc(UpdateData)

    fmt.Println("Start listening")
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))
}

func UpdateData(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    var (
        localVarHTTPMethod = http.MethodPatch
        patchItems         model.PatchItem
    )

    id := config.GetIdFromRequest(request)

    if request.Method == localVarHTTPMethod {

        err := json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&patchItems)
        if err != nil {
            common.WriteError(response, common.ErrBadRequest)
            return
        }

        defer request.Body.Close()

        my.idtime = make(map[string]time.Time)
        my.idtime[id] = time.Now()

        go func() {
            for keyid, t := range my.idtime {

                ts := t.Format(time.RFC3339)

                v, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, ts)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    os.Exit(1)
                }

                timeRemaining := getTimeRemaining(v)

                if timeRemaining.S >= 60 {
                    // delete resouce in database after 60 seconds
                    deleteResourceUsingIdkey(keyid)
                }
            }
        }()

        common.RespondWith3gppJsonPatchJson(response, http.StatusNoContent, nil)
    } else {

        common.WriteError(response, common.ErrMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
}

type count struct {
    S int
}

func getTimeRemaining(t time.Time) count {
    currentTime := time.Now()
    difference := t.Sub(currentTime)

    seconds := int(difference.Seconds())

    return count{
        S: seconds,
    }
}

func deleteResourceUsingIdkey(idkey string) {
    // do delete here
}
```

Comment: 1. yes, 2. also possible. If you want to detect when a client stops polling, you need to keep a record of the clients and the time of last request they've made.

Comment: How can i implement it. Can you provide me with some links or some steps. Am still new in programming.

Comment: There are numerous ways to implement this, it could even be done entirely in the database. The logic sounds pretty straightforward - delete the data if the client hasn't updated it within a certain amount of time. Recommending external resources or answers that require long tutorials are not appropriate for StackOverflow. [ask]

Comment: How can i implement it. Can you provide me with some links or some steps. Am still new in programming. I can keep the ids of the clients maped to time of their last request in some slice. But how i use it. Can you help me with some format or some example code.